# Rails 3 - How to do a find_all_by with a single exception (removing a single record from the resulting array)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, conditional-statements

I have a case where I must use find_all_by; I have a cookie session hash which is limited in size (4kb), so instead of storing the records I need themselves, I'm storing just the IDs in an array.  Thus, find_all_by allows me to find those records directly on the Model/Class.  E.g.,

```
@data = Data.find_all_by_id(session[:search_results])
```

However I need to remove the search result currently being viewed from this list.

Normally I could do a

```
find (:all, conditions: ["id != ?", current_user.id])
```

But since find_all_by returns the ActiveRecord query as an Array, and doesn't seem to support a condition like that, I'm a bit confused on the best approach.

Furthermore, I can't do an Array difference() (e.g., @data - @current_user) where @current_user is an AR object, because it can't do difference on an Array vs an AR object (could I perhaps convert the AR object to an array and go this route?)

How can I subtract a single record from the Array I receive from my Class.find_by_all call?

Comment: have you thought about using `where`? I am not sure if I am understanding your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@data = Data.where("id in (?) AND id != ?", session[:search_results], current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ActiveRecord `where` method. It returns and `ActiveRecord::Relation` Object, which you can concatenate `find` method to.

```
@data = Data.where(id: session[:search_results])
@data.find(current_user.id)
```

It just makes one DB request.